# pandas version is not updated after installing a new version on databricks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, databricks

I am trying to solve a problem of pandas when I run python3.7 code on databricks.

The error is:

```
 ImportError: cannot import name 'roperator' from 'pandas.core.ops' (/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py)
```

the pandas version:

```
pd.__version__
0.24.2
```

I run

```
 from pandas.core.ops import roperator
```

well on my laptop with

```
pandas 0.25.1
```

So, I tried to upgrade pandas on databricks.

```
%sh pip uninstall -y pandas
Successfully uninstalled pandas-1.1.2

%sh pip install pandas==0.25.1
 Collecting pandas==0.25.1
 Downloading pandas-0.25.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.4 MB)
 Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in /databricks/conda/envs/databricks-ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas==0.25.1) (2.8.0)
 Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /databricks/conda/envs/databricks-ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas==0.25.1) (1.16.2)
 Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /databricks/conda/envs/databricks-ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas==0.25.1) (2018.9)
 Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /databricks/conda/envs/databricks-ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas==0.25.1) (1.12.0)
 Installing collected packages: pandas
 ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. 
  This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

  We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

  mlflow 1.8.0 requires alembic, which is not installed.
  mlflow 1.8.0 requires prometheus-flask-exporter, which is not installed.
  mlflow 1.8.0 requires sqlalchemy<=1.3.13, which is not installed.
  sklearn-pandas 2.0.1 requires numpy>=1.18.1, but you'll have numpy 1.16.2 which is incompatible.
   sklearn-pandas 2.0.1 requires pandas>=1.0.5, but you'll have pandas 0.25.1 which is incompatible.
   sklearn-pandas 2.0.1 requires scikit-learn>=0.23.0, but you'll have scikit-learn 0.20.3 which is incompatible.
   sklearn-pandas 2.0.1 requires scipy>=1.4.1, but you'll have scipy 1.2.1 which is incompatible.
   Successfully installed pandas-0.25.1
```

When I run:

```
 import pandas as pd
  pd.__version__
```

it is still:

```
 0.24.2
```

Did I missed something ?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's really recommended to install libraries via [cluster initialization script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html).  The `%sh` command is executed only on the driver node, but not on the executor nodes. And it also doesn't affect Python instance that is already running.

The correct solution will be to use `dbutils.library` [commands](https://kb.databricks.com/libraries/library-install-latency.html), like this:

```py
dbutils.library.installPyPI("pandas", "1.0.1")
dbutils.library.restartPython()
```

this will install library to all places, but it will require restarting of the Python to pickup new libraries.

[image]

Also, although it's possible to specify only package name, it's recommended to specify version explicitly, as some of the library version may not be compatible with runtime.  Also, consider usage of the newer runtimes where library versions are already updated - check the [release notes for runtimes](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/releases.html) to figure out the library versions installed out of the box.

For newer Databricks runtimes you can use new magic commands: `%pip` and `%conda` to install dependencies.  See the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries.html) for more details.

Comment: After pandas is installed and python is restarted, it will be installed on all nodes of the cluster. What if the cluster is restarted again ? Do I need to rerun the dbutils again ?

Comment: I didn’t check, but if it’s just restarted, I think that it should stay. But if you want to guarantee - use in it script to install pandas